# Installing only new packages from composer.json

Tags: composer-php, laravel-forge

I'm trying to make composer update only newly added packages to `composer.json` i.e when I manually add a package dependency to the `composer.json` file, it should update the `composer.lock` file only for the new package; the rest of the packages should be at the same version as before. I tried running `composer update --lock` but I don't think it does what I'm trying to achieve and it took a lot of time to finish. I checked the commands on composer's documentation but can't find one to achieve my wish. Any advice or workaround will be appreciated.

Note: I'm using Laravel Forge, so there is a 2 minutes deployment limit.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install only new packages with composer you should run
`composer install`
Because `composer update` will install your new packages but will update and all the other already installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the name of the package as an argument to the `update` command. This will perform a partial update: `composer update the-package/you-want-to-update`

Comment: Is there a way for composer to automatically understand which package is new in composer.json?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is related to your (guessed) current workflow: To add a new package you edit the `composer.json` file and then run `composer update` - wishing to only add/update that new file.

If that is true, here is the solution:

`composer require new/package` will add the newest possible version (taking into account the currently installed packages) of the new package. Benefits: Only one command line, and no fiddling with JSON content.

If you already know which version you want, you could also run `composer require new/package:^2.1.25@beta` (or whatever version and stability level you want - this example is exaggerating a bit). If this version is incompatible with existing packages, nothing will get installed, everything will get rolled back, and you get an error message.